# How to format query result in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table called EMP which has a column called JOB. Now, JOB column has various entries like CLERK, SALESMAN, MANAGER, etc. I want to fetch all rows(&columns) where JOB = 'CLERK' but instead of displaying 'CLERK' I want to display 'NEW CLERK'. I am not supposed to change the value in the table but display it different while querying. Is this possible?

[Sorry if it doesn't make sense - it's a homework question]

Comment: @Declan_K it's not about `coalesce`. did you mean `decode`?

Comment: While the `COALESCE` function is useful, I don't see how it would be applied to meet the specified requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. Something like this should work:

```
select case JOB when 'CLERK' then 'NEW CLERK' else JOB end as JOB from your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is with a CASE expression, for example:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.job = 'CLERK' THEN 'NEW CLERK' ELSE t.job END AS job
     , t.other_col
  FROM emp t
```

This will return the value from the `JOB` column, except replace occurrences of `'CLERK'` with the literal value of `'NEW CLERK'`.

If you have several different replacements to do, the search form of the CASE expression can be handy:

```
SELECT CASE t.job 
       WHEN 'CLERK' THEN 'NEW CLERK'
       WHEN 'SALESMAN' THEN 'GOOD SALESMAN'
       ELSE t.job
       END AS job
     , t.other_col
  FROM emp t
```

The 'search' form is just a shorter way of writing:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN t.job = 'CLERK' THEN 'NEW CLERK'
       WHEN t.job = 'SALESMAN' THEN 'GOOD SALESMAN'
       ELSE t.job
       END AS job
     , t.other_col
  FROM emp t
```

---

If you are only returning rows that have 'CLERK' in the JOB column, then you could simply return a literal in the statement:

```
SELECT 'NEW CLERK' AS job 
     , t.other_col
  FROM emp t
 WHERE t.job = 'CLERK'
```

--or--

```
SELECT 'NEW '||t.job AS job 
     , t.other_col
  FROM emp t
 WHERE t.job = 'CLERK'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use case statement

```
SELECT  empno,
                ename,
                CASE WHEN job = 'CLERK' THEN 'NEW CLERK' ELSE job END job,
                mgr,
                hiredate,
                sal,
                comm,
                deptno
      FROM  emp
     WHERE  job = 'CLERK'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN JOB = 'CLERK'
         THEN 'NEW CLERK'
    END
FROM EMP
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm)

Answer (score 1):

if you already filter by job, you can display the new value directly as a constant.

```
SELECT 'NEW CLERK' as job
  FROM EMP 
 WHERE job='CLERK'
```

you also can use `decode` instead of `CASE`:

```
SELECT decode(job,'CLERK','NEW CLERK',job)
  FROM EMP
```